# Modifying memory with Ollydbg

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I created a basic text document that represents an html webpage with the basic tags such as `head` and `body`. Inside the head tag, I put the ASCII characters `AEAEAEAEAEAEAEAE` which on the file turns into `0x41454145414541454145`

If I open up Ollydbg and from that application, open up Notepad++, and from that application open the html document, I can then go back to Ollydbg and select the **memory map** window and hit `ctrl+b` to open the search dialog. I can search for the hex characters, find them easily, and then modify them. The results of the modification of memory from Ollydbg appear on the Notepad++ text editor. Where there was once AEs are now Gs.

Now if I try this same process, but instead of opening up Notepad++, I open Internet Explorer. I open the memory map, and search for the known hex, I cannot locate the data anywhere. Additionally, the Ollydbg search always stops at certain memory chunks that are full of `?`s and the section is labeled as `Priv` for the type.

This also happens when I try to open the html file in the regular windows notpad.

Is there a reason that I cannot find this data when trying using Olldby to search the memory maps of Microsoft products like notepad and Internet Explorer?

FYI I am using a Windows 8 machine, 32 bit.